# Streaming FFMPEG RTSP in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I wish to stream an RTSP feed from my camera through my C# client app and eventually recieve it on my server.

To test it I decided to stream it through my client and then recieve the jpeg frames from it as well.

I 1st tested my command line arguments in a DOS window.

It worked in that it stream to an output file without incident.

So, now I ported it over to my C# app and used the Process Class.

This is the code:

```
   Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            process.Start();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[200000];
            baseStream = process.StandardOutput.BaseStream as FileStream;
            bool gotHeader = false;
            bool imgFound = false;
            int counter = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                byte bit1 = (byte)baseStream.ReadByte();
                buffer[counter] = bit1;
                if (bit1 == 217 && gotHeader)
                {
                    if (buffer[counter - 1] == 255)
                    {
                        byte[] jpeg = new byte[counter];
                        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, jpeg, 0, counter);
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(jpeg))
                        {
                            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                            ms.Close();
                        }
                        imgFound = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (bit1 == 216)
                {
                    if (buffer[counter - 1] == 255)
                    {
                        gotHeader = true;
                    }
                }
                if (imgFound)
                {
                    counter = 0;
                    buffer = new byte[200000];
                    imgFound = false;
                    gotHeader = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            //log error here
        }
    });
```

But I do not get any images I just get the byte value of 255 at this line:

```
buffer[counter] = bit1;
```

So.. what am I doing wrong please?

Thanks